# How can SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE in firefox be further examined?

Tags: tls, crl

A https website, which is not under my control, leads to an error message `SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE` in Firefox 51.
The CRL (url embedded in the certificate) does **not** distrust the sites certificate.
`openssl s_client` has no objections, neither do other TLS capable clients (Firefox 50, MS Edge).

**Q:** What would be a canonical way to figure out what happened here, just  making firefox tell me what the problem is? (workarounds see below)

Comment: What's the site? What CA does it use? Is it StartSSL or WoSign? Alternately, maybe is it using SHA-1?

Comment: Does a current Chrome browser give you an error?

Answer (score 1):

**General Troubleshooting:**

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/
May or may not include a statement about the trust store status of the certificates in the chain.

**Cheating:**

Manually check the news & figure out that the certificate authority that created the certificate was distrusted by mozilla starting with the Firefox version in question. In my case, it was StartCom/WoSign.

https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2016/10/24/distrusting-new-wosign-and-startcom-certificates/

**Manual checking:**

1. Manually extract the mozilla trusted certificates of each channel from hg.mozilla.org e.g. using
   `https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/mk-ca-bundle.pl`
2. `openssl verfiy -verbose -CAfile ca-bundle-channel-xyz.pem`
3. compare result for different channels `mozilla-release` / `mozilla-beta`

Note: This only helps for completely removed roots - however mozilla has a special rule about the notBefore date in place for StartCom, which will not be visible this way.